# Weighted Fair queuing algorithm doing round-robin with just 2 packet flow

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-programming, queue

I tried implementing a simple simulation of the Weighted Fair queuing algorithm.

But I noticed an issue when using only 2 packet flow, the algorithm is not letting twice the amount of T1 packet as it should because they are half the size of T2 packet. Instead it simply do round-robin between the 2 flow.

I understand the problem is that it take some time for T1 to add another packet to the queue and the Weighted Fair queuing have the time to run when T1 queue is empty.

This does not seem to be the expected behavior, am I missing something in the algorithm that would fix this corner case?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Packet
    {
        public string name;
        public ManualResetEventSlim mres;

        public long virFinish;
        public long packetSize;
        public Packet(string pname, long p_virFinish, long p_packetSize)
        {
            name = pname;
            mres = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            virFinish = p_virFinish;
            packetSize = p_packetSize;
        }
    }

    public class Queue
    {
        public ConcurrentQueue<Packet> q = new ConcurrentQueue<Packet>();
        public long virStart;
        public long lastVirFinish;
    }

    public class FairQueue
    {
        long VirtualTime; // system virtual time
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, Queue> queues = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Queue>();
        public FairQueue() {
            VirtualTime = long.MinValue;
            queues.GetOrAdd("t1", new Queue());
            queues.GetOrAdd("t2", new Queue());
            queues.GetOrAdd("t3", new Queue());
        }

        public ManualResetEventSlim Write(string queueName, long packetSize)
        {
            var queue = queues[queueName];
            Volatile.Write(ref queue.virStart, Math.Max(VirtualTime, queue.lastVirFinish));
            var packetFinish = queue.virStart + packetSize;
            var packet = new Packet(queueName, packetFinish, packetSize);
            queue.q.Enqueue(packet);


            Volatile.Write(ref queue.lastVirFinish, packetFinish);

            UpdateVirtualClock(queue);

            return packet.mres;
        }

        private void UpdateVirtualClock(Queue queue)
        {
            long minStart = queue.virStart;
            foreach (var item in queues)
            {
                if (!item.Value.q.IsEmpty)
                {
                    minStart = Math.Min(item.Value.virStart, minStart);
                }
            }
            Volatile.Write(ref VirtualTime, Math.Max(VirtualTime, minStart));
        }


        // return queue with smallest lastVirFinish
        public Queue SelectQueue()
        {
            long minVirFinish = long.MaxValue; // infinity
            Queue selected = null;
            foreach (var queue in queues)
            {

                if (!queue.Value.q.IsEmpty)
                {
                    var lastVirFinish = Volatile.Read(ref queue.Value.lastVirFinish);
                    if (lastVirFinish < minVirFinish) {
                        minVirFinish = queue.Value.lastVirFinish;
                        selected = queue.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            return selected;
        }

        public Packet Send()
        {
            var selectedQueue = SelectQueue();
            if (selectedQueue != null)
            {
                Packet p;
                selectedQueue.q.TryDequeue(out p);
                /* Set the start and the finish times of the remaining packets in the queue */
                if (!selectedQueue.q.IsEmpty)
                {
                    var next = selectedQueue.q.Take(1).First();
                    selectedQueue.virStart = selectedQueue.lastVirFinish;
                    selectedQueue.lastVirFinish = selectedQueue.virStart + next.packetSize;
                }
                return p;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


    }


    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FairQueue fq = new FairQueue();

            // Task that enqueue packet
            var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
             () => {
                 while (true)
                 {
                     System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                     sw.Start();
                     var s1 = fq.Write("t1", 100);
                     s1.Wait();
                     sw.Stop();
                 }
             }
            );

            // Task that enqueue packet
            var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
             () => {
                 while (true)
                 {
                     System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                     sw.Start();
                     var s1 = fq.Write("t2", 200);
                     s1.Wait();
                     sw.Stop();
                 }
             }
            );

            // Loop that run the Weighted Fair Queue Algorithm
            while (true)
            {
                var toSend = fq.Send();
                if (toSend != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(toSend.name);
                    Thread.Sleep((int)toSend.packetSize);
                    toSend.mres.Set();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```